# Tomcat Request postData null

Tags: tomcat, request

My web app works fine in local tomcat server test. But when deploy to a test environment, the app not work right.

So I remote debug the app, just found postData of tomcat request is null, while it does have data in local debug.

That's very weird. I got nothing clue with google.

Comment: Whence is the POST request?  Could it be that you are not sending what you think you are?

Comment: I can see the post data in chrome network.

Comment: Show the lowest level code where the POST data be absent.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer by adding tomcat jar in my runtime and tracing the code.

It was because the test environment tomcat had a wrong configuration.

It sets `maxPostSize=0` of connector in conf/server.xml, so it causes `FailReason.POST_TOO_LARGE` error and would't parse the post data and get a null postData.